# Adding values to an object whilst iterating over data

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a set of JSON - that i need to iterate over as I essentially need to create a string which contains certain identifiers in it.  At the moment I am mapping over the data and then over stimulus list.  ( I have the index which from the event as I only need data from that index).

The problem I have is the cell_id is always the same . And I need to create a string.

```
      const key = `cell_Id${cell_id}:step_Id${item.step_id}:study_id${studyId}:stim_id${item.stimulus_id}`
```

I suspect I need to add things to an object as I am interating over the data - what is the best way to do this?

thanks

Here is the JSON

```
{
  "study_id": 16,

  "data": [
    {
      "cell_id": 23,
      "stimulus_list": [
        {

          "stimulus_id": 96,
          "step_id": 62

        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "cell_id": 24,
      "stimulus_list": [
        {
          "stimulus_id": 95,
          "step_id": 61

        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

 data
      .map(item => item.stimulus_list)
      .map(item => item[index]);
```

Comment: Your requirement is not clear. Please re-phrase. Also, provide expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a nested map over the data and then flatten the result using reduce.

```js
const obj = {
  "study_id": 16,

  "data": [
    {
      "cell_id": 23,
      "stimulus_list": [
        {

          "stimulus_id": 96,
          "step_id": 62

        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "cell_id": 24,
      "stimulus_list": [
        {
          "stimulus_id": 95,
          "step_id": 61

        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

 const res = obj.data
      .map(item => {
      return [].concat(item.stimulus_list.map(stimulus => `cell_Id${item.cell_id}:step_Id${stimulus.step_id}:study_id${obj.study_id}:stim_id${stimulus.stimulus_id}`))
}).reduce((acc, item) => {
   acc = acc.concat(item)
   return acc;
}, [])
console.log(res)
```

Comment: Glad to have helped